# Is there a way to bring up a keyboard when developing in Godot VR?

Tags: godot

Is there a way to bring up the keyboard when developing a VR game in Godot? I'm exporting my game in android and I'm trying to figure out a way to allow the player to enter a name. Is there anyway to do this?

I'm using the following libary- https://github.com/GodotVR/godot_oculus_mobile

Thanks in advance.